# How to make the TTY use my entire screen resolution

Tags: command-line, kernel, tty, administration

I've been using the TTY (CTRL + ALT + F1) and I need it to have full screen resolution. Is it the configuration for the Kernel or for SH I don't have any ideas.

Comment: "full screen resolution" is a graphics concept. Ctrl-Alt-F1 gives you a text terminal (a TTY), not a graphics terminal.

Comment: @waltinator  OK I get it. Can I set a resolution somehow?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a 4K (3840x2160) monitor:

```
sudo apt install fbset
sudo fbset -g 3840 2160 3840 2160 32
```

For Full HD it's `fbset 1920 1080 1920 1080 32` and so on.

[SEO credit to user karol from ArchLinux forums for this solution](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=119015#p934430)